# SSIS Data Conversion task is giving wrong output when source datatype is BIT

Tags: sql-server, ssis, type-conversion, data-conversion, msbi

I have created two tables from below script:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (ISDELETED BIT)

CREATE TABLE Test1 (ISDELETED INT)
```

Table Test data:

[image]

Here datatype of column `isdeleted` in table `test` is `BIT` and in table `test1` datatype is `INT`. So now using SSIS I am trying to load data from `test` table into `Test1` table.

1. screenshot of DFD: Source is TEST and Destination is Test1

[image]

2. Bit to int conversion
   [image]
3. Mapping of converted column with destination
   [image]

After running this package getting below output in Test1 table:

[image]

So as output I am getting data -1 instead of 1.

I think this is SSIS bug. If anyone has a solution on the above problem then please help.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently this is how SSIS converts a bit to an int.
One solution would be to add a derived column with the expression:

```
ISDELETED == True ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: @M.Mohabbati This is a correct SSIS expression syntax. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: you are right and the syntax is ok. that was my fault and I delete it. but your answer doesn't work for me. have you tested it?

Comment: Your approach is an alternative and you don't answer the question. The problem is the output of conversion bit to int that returns -1 instead 1.

Comment: Another approach is to use `SQL Command` in `Source Assistant` and convert the bit filed to int explicitly: `convert(int, IsDeleted)`. I tested it and it works.

Comment: @M.Mohabbati I've tested it and it works.